# Why onchange, onblur and useRef doesn't work with react hook form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, use-ref

I tried to use the useRef hook, onChange, and onBlur with react hook form fields. But it doesn't seem to work for a reason. Can someone please explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an 
attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical 
problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result,
 we can help with that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue here's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75499383/cant-get-useref-to-work-with-react-hook-form