# Can't get useRef() to work with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form, tsx

But it does work when I disable React Hook Form and vice versa but not both together. I just want to focus on the `title` input field on first render. I minified it a little and imports/exports are not included in the snippet because it's usual boilerplate.

When I comment out `ref={refFocus}` RHF works but when I take it in again it won't function. I don't know if this is a conflict with the DOM reference since RHF is working a lot with it too. Might be a version mismatch, typescript error or something's deprecated or incompatible - I have no clue. I'd appreciate any idea.

I already browsed through the questions and found a similar issue but it lacks contents/code example and there's no answer: [Why onchange, onblur and useRef doesn't work with react hook form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72145816/why-onchange-onblur-and-useref-doesnt-work-with-react-hook-form)
And this one is not very alike, I tried that: [How to set focus when using React hook form Controller component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825197/how-to-set-focus-when-using-react-hook-form-controller-component)

For context, It's a simple UI where I can add tiles by filling out a form that's inside a header:
[image: Header form example]

```
const Header = () : JSX.Element => {

  const 
    {setCtxAdded} = useContext(TileListCtx),
    
    addSchema = z.object({
      image: z.string().url({ message: 'Value must contain a valid URL address.' }),
      title: z.string(),
      text: z.string().optional()
    }),
    
    refFocus = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)
  
  useEffect(()=> refFocus.current?.focus(), [])

  type AddFormValidation = z.infer<typeof addSchema>

  const 
    {register, handleSubmit, formState:{errors}} = useForm<AddFormValidation>({ 
      resolver: zodResolver(addSchema) 
    }),

    addTile = async (data: Array<string> | unknown) : Promise<void> => {
      const add: Response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/add', { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      const res: Array<JSON> | any = await add.json()
      setCtxAdded(add.ok)
      if (res.error.code == 'P2002') console.log('Title already exists.')
    }

  return (
    <header>
      <h1>X-5</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addTile)}>
        <input {...register("image")} type='text' placeholder='Image' />
        <input {...register("title")} ref={refFocus} type='text' placeholder='Title' />
        <input {...register("text")} type='text' placeholder='Text' />
        <button>Add Tile</button>
      </form>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React hook form uses refs, but you replaced his ref with your ref.

RHF has setFocus method. Use it instead of your own ref:

```
const {
      register,
      handleSubmit,
      formState: { errors },
      setFocus
    } = useForm<AddFormValidation>(),
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setFocus("title");
  }, [setFocus]);
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addTile)}>
        <input {...register("image")} type="text" placeholder="Image" />
        <input {...register("title")} type="text" placeholder="Title" />
        <input {...register("text")} type="text" placeholder="Text" />
        <button>Add Tile</button>
</form>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-booth-2yg5ve?file=/src/Header.tsx